# VBA Choose value to ListIndex 0

Tags: vba

I have a form which I want to choose the ListIndex of a combobox2 depending on the value of another combobox1.

I tried to use the following code, but didn't succeed.

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range
For Each rng In Sheets("CLIENTES").Range("F2:F300")
    If rng.Value = Me.cmbProfissional.Text Then
    Me.cmbProfissional.ListIndex(0) = rng.Value
    End If
```

Comment: Sorry, can't quite understand what you're after.  I can see you're looping through the range `F2:F300`.  If one of the values in that range is the same as the value selected in the combobox what do you want it to do?  `Me.cmbProfissional.ListIndex = 0` would select the first item in the list?

Comment: Looks like you want to assign it as the first item in the list.

Comment: I want to choose the listindex(0) depending on another combobox. For exemple: when someone choose a patient, I want to check if that patiant have a designated physiotherapist (that will appears on the 1 list - listindex(0) -) or if can be anyone,